# VBScript MSMQ Dead-Letter Queue Count

Tags: vbscript, msmq, dead-letter

I'm trying to get a count of the number of messages in the dead-letter queue using VBScript. 
Here's my code:

```
 Option Explicit 
 Dim mqQ, QueueName 
 set mqQ = CreateObject("MSMQ.MSMQManagement") 
 mqQ.Init "localhost", , "DIRECT=OS:localhost\system$;deadletter" 
 wscript.echo mqQ.MessageCount & " messsages"
```

Here's the error I'm getting:

```
 D:\msmq_queue.vbs(4, 1) MSMQManagement: Operations of the type requested (for example, deleting a queue using a direct format name) are not supported for the format name specified.
```

I use this format to grab private message count, but I'm getting this error in dead-letter.

Comment: This could be because I can't directly call this queue with MSMQManagement. Any idea how to call the queue with MSMQQueueInfo?